# Pandas: List of maximum values of difference from previous rows in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a new column 'BEST' to this dataframe, which contains a list of the names of the columns which meet these criteria:

- Subtract from the current value in each column the value in the row that is 2 rows back
- The column that has the highest result of this subtraction will be listed in 'BEST'
- If more more than one column shares the same highest result, they all get listed
- If all columns have the same result, they all get listed

**Input:**

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  3  2  1
2  5  2  4
3 -3  0  2
4  6  3  4
```

**Desired result:**

```
   A  B  C        BEST
0  1  2  3          []
1  3  2  1          []
2  5  2  4       ['A']
3 -3  0  2       ['C']
4  6  3  4  ['A', 'B']
```

Explanation for the result in the new column 'BEST' for each row:

- **Rows 0 and 1:** Empty list in 'BEST', because 2 rows back does not exist.
- **Row 2:** Calculate for column A: 5 - 1 = **4**, for column B: 2 - 2 = **0**, for column C: 4 - 3 = **1**  **-> highest is 'A'**
- **Row 3**: Calculate for column A: -3 - 1 = **-4**, for column B: 0 - 2 = **-2**, for column C: 2 - 3 = **-1**  **-> highest is 'C'**
- **Row 4:** Calculate for column A: 6 - 5 = **1**, for column B: 3 - 2 = **1**, for column C: 4 - 4 = **0**  **-> highest are both ['A', 'B']**

**Code to generate the dataframe:**

```
import io, pandas as pd

df = io.StringIO("""
A|B|C
1|2|3
3|2|1
5|2|4
-3|0|2
6|3|4
""")
df = pd.read_csv(df, sep='|')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shift()`, `apply()` and `np.where` to do so.
Try this:

```
df['Best'] = (df - df.shift(2)).iloc[2:].apply(lambda x: list(df.columns[np.where(x==max(x))]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
print(df)

A   B   C   Best
0   1   2   3   NaN
1   3   2   1   NaN
2   5   2   4   [A]
3   -3  0   2   [C]
4   6   3   4   [A, B]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's a great one line answer!

Answer (score 3):

First use `shift` and `subtract` to get the diff, then replace the maximum values with the column name and drop the others.

```
df['BEST'] = (
    df.subtract(df.shift(2))
    .apply(lambda x: [df.columns[i] for i,e in enumerate(x) if e==max(x)], axis=1)
)

    A   B   C   BEST
0   1   2   3   []
1   3   2   1   []
2   5   2   4   [A]
3   -3  0   2   [C]
4   6   3   4   [A, B]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
maximum=df.sub(df.shift(2)).max(skipna=False,axis=1)
#finded the maximum value
df['Best']=(df.where(df.sub(df.shift(2)).isin(maximum))
          .T
          .apply(lambda x:x.dropna().index.tolist()))
```

Output of `df`:

```
    A   B   C   Best
0   1   2   3   []
1   3   2   1   []
2   5   2   4   [A]
3   -3  0   2   [C]
4   6   3   4   [A, B]
```